# NLog detect if LogLevel is enabled for Target

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

Is there any way I can find out if a `LogLevel` is enabled for a specific target?

**Situation**
NLog Version: `5.1.3`
Plattfrom: `.Net 7`
Config: `XML File` and `configured programmatically`

We have many rules, which are nested.
The default behavior of NLog is that if a rule does not fit based on the `LogLevel`, it checks if another rule could match.
However, this leads to the fact that I do not have the possibility to disable the logs of a specific namespace.

The LogLevels can be changed by the user at runtime via the GUI. This is important to find errors.

So that we can disable the logs from a specific namespace, we added the `NullTarget`.
This takes all log messages that I don't want to see in the console or the LogFile.
This also works very well. But now we noticed that when I check with `Log.IsTraceEnabled`, I always get `true`, because the logs always go to NullTarget.
This leads partly to a performance problem.

Therefore I would like to know if it is possible to exclude the NullTarget from `Log.IsTraceEnabled`.

Example of our rules: (This is how the rules were created)

```cs
Pattern: BroadcastSuite.Common.Data.DatabaseContext*        Final: True  MinLevel: Trace MaxLevel: Fatal Targets: NullTarget   
Pattern: BroadcastSuite.Common.Data.DatabaseContext*        Final: True  MinLevel: Off   MaxLevel: Off   Targets: SplitTarget    <<<<<
Pattern: BroadcastSuite.Common.Data.PlaceholderReplacer*    Final: False MinLevel: Off   MaxLevel: Off   Targets: NullTarget   
Pattern: BroadcastSuite.Common.Data.PlaceholderReplacer*    Final: True  MinLevel: Trace MaxLevel: Fatal Targets: SplitTarget    <<<<<
Pattern: BroadcastSuite.Common.Data*                        Final: True  MinLevel: Trace MaxLevel: Trace Targets: NullTarget   
Pattern: BroadcastSuite.Common.Data*                        Final: True  MinLevel: Debug MaxLevel: Fatal Targets: SplitTarget    <<<<<
Pattern: BroadcastSuite.Common*                             Final: True  MinLevel: Trace MaxLevel: Debug Targets: NullTarget   
Pattern: BroadcastSuite.Common*                             Final: True  MinLevel: Info  MaxLevel: Fatal Targets: SplitTarget   
Pattern: BroadcastSuite*                                    Final: True  MinLevel: Trace MaxLevel: Debug Targets: NullTarget   
Pattern: BroadcastSuite*                                    Final: True  MinLevel: Info  MaxLevel: Fatal Targets: SplitTarget   
Pattern: *                                                  Final: True  MinLevel: Trace MaxLevel: Debug Targets: NullTarget   
Pattern: *                                                  Final: True  MinLevel: Info  MaxLevel: Fatal Targets: SplitTarget
```

In the example you can see that

- `BroadcastSuite.Common.Data*` is set to `Debug`
- `BroadcastSuite.Common.Data.PlaceholderReplacer*` is set to `Trace`
- `BroadcastSuite.Common.Data.DatabaseContext*` is set to `Off`.

(In the following picture, you can see it a bit clearer)

This gives us the possibility that I can see everything that comes from the `PlaceholderReplacer`, but the logs from `DatabaseContext` are not shown, even though `Data` is on `Debug`.

[image: Logger Rules]

Comment: Instead of using `NullTarget` then just have LoggingRule without any targets (Ex. `writeTo=""`), then `Logger.IsTraceEnabled = false` when no targets configured.

Comment: @Rolf Kristensen  If I pass `null` as the target, it does not work. `new LoggingRule("BroadcastSuite.Common.Data.DatabaseContext*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, levelForNullTarget, null)`

Comment: The `NLog.Logger.IsEnabled` function only checks if a `TargetWithFilterChain` exists (`GetTargetsForLevelSafe(level) != null`) and not if a `Target `exists. (`GetTargetsForLevelSafe(level)?.Target != null`). I can create a pull request for this change.

Comment: When not having a target, then just use the `LoggingRule`-constructor without Target-parameter (Ex. default-constructor). And if necessary assign the `LoggerNamePattern` and call `EnableLoggingForLevels(..)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works now exactly as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `NullTarget` then just have `LoggingRule` without any targets (Ex. writeTo=""), then `Logger.IsTraceEnabled = false` when no targets configured.

When not having a target, then just use the `LoggingRule`-constructor without Target-parameter (Ex. default-constructor). And if necessary assign the `LoggerNamePattern` and call `EnableLoggingForLevels(..)`